# Row tile have some extra space on the left side

Tags: flutter

So i have a simple widget tree like this

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.editable
        ? SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (int index = 0; index < points.length; index++)
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Checkbox(
                      value: checkedPoints[index],
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() => checkedPoints[index] = val!);
                      },
                    ),
                    title: TextField(
                      //enabled: false,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      onSubmitted: (value) => _onSubmitted(),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        : Row(children: [
            Checkbox(
              value: widget.checked,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.checked = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(widget.label)
          ]);
  }
```

But for whatever reason there's some extra spacing on the left next to each new row. I would like that the checkbox and text would shift to the start of the screen on the left side as shown on screenshot nr.2 I've tried using the mainAxisAlignment and set it to start but it does nothing as it set like this by default.

Any Ideas how can I achieve what I intended (2nd screenshot)? I bet it's something simple but I can't figure this out.

[image]
[image]